# pytest: test for import of subpackage

Tags: python, pytest, python-import

I want to do the following. In my project `a` I have a factory class `Fac` with instance `fac=Fac()`, where certain classes register to. These classes reside in a subpackage `a.b`.

If I do a plain `import a`, the subpackage `a.b` is not imported, no classes are registered, and thus `fac.registered_classes` is an empty list.

After an import of subpackage `b` `fac.registered_classes` gets filled with the classes in subpackage `b`.

To not confuse the user, I added the line

`import .b` in the `__init__.py` of package `a`.

Now, I'd like to write a test with `pytest` that basically passes, if the `fac.registered_classes` is not empty; so noone accidentally erases that line in my `__init__.py`. Lets call that test `test_import_b`

Different tests of course also test functionality of subpackage `b`, thus importing `b` themselves explicitly.

However, it seems that all imports during test runs are available for *all* tests.
While just running the single test `test_import_b` fails if the import line is removed in `__init__.py`, it does not anymore if all tests are ran simultaneously.

What am I supposed to do, to make my test setup work?

Answer (score 1):

This is correct py.test and Python behavior. Module body level code is run when to module is imported. Python virtual machine maintains imported modules per-process.

I do not believe there is a good solution to achieve the behavior you want. Two strategies come to my mind

- Do not ever register anything implicitly on module import only - make registering everything explicit through a function call like having your `init()`
- In the tests that explicitly need to import and have register run, import it at the beginning of the test or make a fixture that does the import

E.g.

```py
def test_boohoo():
     import a.b
     # Test goes here
```

Comment: I see, that it's solving the problem somehow. On the other hand it's including functionality I on purpose did not implement. I guess, the user should not be forced to do the register step himself.

Comment: You can write a generic function `register_all()` the library user can call - side-effects on imports are something that will always help you to blow off a toe or two from yourself.

Comment: What I don't like about that approach is, that even though it's a generic call, it's an additional call, which from the user perspective may seem unnecessary. The user will never have to call a `register_something_else()` function. But I see the downsides of that approach. I'm just not happy with both options I have.